# How to get List for hasMany relation in Fixture adapter in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to ember.. I have 2 models..

```
Music.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    dob : DS.attr('date'),
    songs : DS.hasMany('song',{async:true})
});

Music.Artist.FIXTURES=[
    {
        id:1,
        name:'John',
        dob:new Date(),
        songs:['1','2']
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'Robbin',
        dob:new Date(),
        songs:['1','2']
    }
];

Music.Song = DS.Model.extend({
    title:DS.attr('string'),
    artists:DS.hasMany('artist',{async:true})
});

Music.Song.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id:1,
        title:'A day to remember',
        artists:[1,2]
    },
    {
        id:2,
        title:'Cant live without you',
        artists:[1,2]
    }
];
```

I want for url "/songs/id"... I get all the songs that has an artist with the given id.

```
Music.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('songs',{path:'/songs/:id'});
});

Music.SongsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(param){
        var artist = this.store.find('artist',param.id);

        return artist.get('songs');
    }   

});
```

But it returns undefined... How to get the list of songs that are related to the Artist.

Is there any way i can achieve this by using only routes.

How to read the array of songs, if not through get.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current versions of Ember (1.6.1) and Ember-Data (1.0.0-beta.9), here's how I got your example working. I changed your route naming, I think you really want something like `/artists/:artist_id` which will list the artist's data, including all his songs.

Your `Artist` and `Song` model declarations seem fine, but I declared the fixtures like so:

```
Music.Artist.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id:1,
      name:'John',
      dob:new Date(),
      songs:['1','2']
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:'Robbin',
      dob:new Date(),
      songs:['1','2']
    }
  ]
});

Music.Song.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id:1,
      title:'A day to remember',
      artists:[1,2]
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title:'Cant live without you',
      artists:[1,2]
    }  
  ]
});
```

For the router:

```
Music.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('artists');
  this.resource('artist', { path: '/artists/:artist_id' });
});
```

For the routes:

```
var Music.ArtistsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('artist');
  }
});

var Music.ArtistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('artist', params["artist_id"]);
  }
});
```

For your templates:

```
// artists.hbs
<ul>
{{#each}}
  <li>{{#link-to 'artist' this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}  
</ul>

// artist.hbs
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<hr>
<h2>Songs</h2>
<ul>
  {{#each songs}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
  {{/each}}  
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer, but you could highlight the changes and the reasoning behind them.